# Highcharts "undefined is not an object" error

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I saw other related posts but I am unable to locate an answer, so I am revamping this topic.

I have been using highchairs for over 2 months until today, with no problems. Today i get the error Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b:center'). It seems like all the javascript are failing

```
animate: function(a) {
var b = this, d = b.points, f = b.startAngleRad;
a || (H(d, function(a) {
var c =
a.graphic, d = a.shapeArgs;
c && (c.attr({
r: a.startR || b.center[3] / 2, //Line where error is shown
start: f,
end: f
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide MVP with this problem?

Comment: How do you load Highcharts? Do you load specific version? Yesterdey was releasing a new Highcharts version, so I guess this the reason.

Comment: I am loading the charts via CDN:   
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

Comment: The only chart that doesn´t work is the "solid gauge" <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>. The others actually work

Comment: Try to use the previous version https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.6/highcharts.js - on production you should use a specific version and check if it works before the update. It might be broken in the latest Highcharts release or in your code - it hard to say until you reproduce the error.

Comment: Fixed it! Morganfree, yours is the correct answer - I just reverted the CDN code to an older version. Thanks!